# Is it possible to 'Include' shadow navigation properties?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a parent entity (Catalog) with child entities (Category).  I have no need to expose the navigation property of child entities:

```
public class Catalog
{
    string _name;
    List<Category> _categorys;
}

public class Category
{
    string _name;
}
```

I want to include Categorys in a query on Catalog:

```
return await _context.Catalog
    .Include(c => EF.Property<List<Category>>(c, "_categorys"));
```

But I get exception:

> The expression 'Property(c, "_categorys")' is invalid inside an
> 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't
> => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t =>
> (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be
> filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending),
> Skip or Take operations.

I have configured the relationship on the Category as follows:

```
builder.HasOne<Catalog>()
    .WithMany("_categorys")
    .HasForeignKey("CatalogId")
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Comment: First, this is not shadow property, but real property/field not exposed publicly. Second, in order to eager load it you first need to map it as navigation property part of the relationship. How you did that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to 'Include' shadow navigation properties?

No, it's not possible because EF Core so far does not support shadow *navigation* properties.

But in the shown example `_children` is *not* shadow property (shadow properties are the ones that do not exist in the objects are maintained purely in the change tracker internal data structures, and are lost when the object goes out of the change tracker), but regular property/field, just not exposed publicly.

I'm not going to comment how many benefits of the ORM are you loosing by not exposing it, so answering your concrete question.

Yes, it's possible to eager load such properties (assuming they were mapped correctly through fluent configuration to the corresponding relationship). But `EF.Property` method is only for primitive (non navigation) properties. For navigation properties you have to use the `Include` [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.include?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include%60%601);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-5.0) receiving `string` argument and pass dot separated string containing the path to the navigation property. e.g.

```cs
return await _context.Catalog
    .Include("_categorys");
```

Comment: Great stuff!  Thanks for the answer and explanation.